# Determining if the Presentation Settings for a Sitecore Item has been overriden

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6

This is one way of determining if the Presentation Settings of an Item have been overriden:

```
var contextItemPresentationSettings = Sitecore.Context.Item["__Renderings"];

var standardValuesPresentationSettings = Sitecore.Context.Item.Template.StandardValues["__Renderings"];

var presentationSettingsMatch = contextItemPresentationSettings == standardValuesPresentationSettings;
```

Is there a better way of determining if the Presentation Settings for an Item have been overriden?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this:

```
Sitecore.Context.Item.Fields[Sitecore.FieldIDs.LayoutField].ContainsStandardValue
```

FYI, `Sitecore.FieldIDs.LayoutField` is a constant that hold the value of the `__Renderings` field ID, it's better to use those when retrieving Sitecore system fields.

Comment: Be careful there is a bug in certain versions of sitecore with that property. Read this as well http://seankearney.com/post/Field-ContainsStandardValue-in-Sitecore-is-Buggy.aspx